# Show that the function $f: x \rightarrow x^2$ is uniformly continuous on the set $S = \bigcup \{[n,n + n^{-2}] ~|~n \in \mathbb N\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Show that the function $f: x \rightarrow x^2$ is uniformly continuous on the set $S = \bigcup \{[~n~,~n + n^{-2}~] ~|~n \in \mathbb N\}$

**Attempt:**

Let $S_n = [~n~,~n + n^{-2}~]$.
then diam $S_n = \dfrac {1}{n^2}$ which is clearly dependent on $n$.

If we limit the set $S$ upto $m$ natural numbers, then surely the function is uniformly continuous (**since** a function which is uniformly continuous over each disjoint subset which are **finite** in number and at non zero distance from each other, is also uniformly continuous over their union).

But, here the diameter of each $S_n$ is ever changing with each natural number.

Any advice on how to move forward with this problem will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^2 -y^2|= |x-y||x+y|.$$

Thus for $x$ and $y$ in $[k,k+\frac {1}{k^2}]$ we have $$ |f(x)-f(y)|\le \frac {1}{k^2} (2k+ \frac {2}{k^2})$$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be an arbitrary small number.

Pick a natural number $n_0$ such that $$ \frac {1}{n_0^2} (2n_0+ \frac {2} {n_0^2})<\epsilon$$

If $n\ge n_0$ then   $$         \frac {1}{n^2} (2n+ \frac {2} {n^2}) < \frac {1}{n_0^2} (2n_0+ \frac {2} {n_0^2})<\epsilon$$

The first two interval intersect at $x=2$, therefore the union of the first two interval, $[1,2\frac {1}{4}]$requires special attention.

The function $ f(x) =x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,2\frac {1}{4}],$ thus for our given $\epsilon$ there exists a $ \delta _1$ satisfying the condition of uniform continuity on  $[1,2\frac {1}{4}].$

Note that $f(x)=x^2$ is also uniformly continuous on each of closed intervals $$ [k,k+\frac {1}{k^2}]$$ for $k=3,...,n_0-1$.

We can find $$\delta _3,     \delta _4,   \delta _5,....,     \delta _{n_0-1}$$ to satisfy the condition of uniform continuity on $ [k,k+\frac{1}{k^2}]$.

Let $\delta_2 =  \delta_1$ and choose $$\delta  = min( 1/4, \delta _1,     \delta _2,   \delta_3,....,     \delta _{n_0-1})$$.

We have $$ |x-y| < \delta \implies |x^2 -y^2| < \epsilon $$ on the given union.

Thus $f(x) = x^2$ is uniformly continuous on the given union.

Comment: the values of $n$ are infinite. It's not possible to pick a minimum value for $\delta_i$

Comment: We picked a specific n such that $ \frac {1}{n^2} (2n+ \frac {2}{n^2}) <\epsilon$ and $i$ runs from 1  to that specific n-1, we are dealing with finite number of    δi

Comment: @MathMan  I have edited my solution to take care of that problem. Thanks for attention.

Comment: There are a few details that probably explain the confusion of the person asking the question: 1) The first two intervals are not disjoint, so $\delta_1,\delta_2$ need to be modified accordingly. 2) In order to avoid other unwanted overlaps, you probably want to impose in addition a condition such as $\delta<1/3$ or some such, so points from different intervals do not interact "by accident". 3) You may also want to explain why your $\delta$ works for all $n$, including $n>n_0$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thanks, I did not notice that the first two intervals are not disjoint. I need to work on those points to fix the solution.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I have modified my solution to address the concerns.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani thanks for answering. Could you explain why the solution works for $n \ge n_0$. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if wrong:

$f(x) = x^2$ , $x \gt 0$, $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$:

$f$ is uniformly continuos on each compact interval $[n, n+n^{-2}].$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given, $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$:

For $x,y \in [k,k+k^{-2}]$ there exist a $\delta_{k}$

such that $|x-y| \lt \delta_{k}$ implies

$|f(x)-f(y)| \lt \epsilon.$

Now: Let $x,y \in [n,n+n^{-2}] :$

$|f(x)-f(y)| = |x-y||x+y| \le $

$1/n^{2}(2n+2/n^{2})=2(1/n +1/n^4)$.

Let $n_0$ be such that :

$(\star)$ : $|f(x)-f(y)| \le $

$2(2/n_0+1/n_0^2) \lt \epsilon.$

Choose $\delta \le \min(\delta_1, \delta_2,...\delta_{n_0}).$

This $\delta$ qualifies :

For  intervals with $ n \le n_0$ :

$|x-y|\lt \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|\lt \epsilon.$

Now a bit trickier :

For $n\gt n_0:$

$|x-y| \le 1/n^2$ and using $(\star)$:

$ |x^2-y^2| \lt \epsilon.$

Our $\delta$ is also good for the intervals with $n\gt n_0$:

1)$ \delta \lt $ interval length $ 1/n^2 $, $(\star)$ is valid.

2) $ \delta \ge $ than interval length $1/n^2$ is also

OK,  since  we restrict $x,y$ to the domain

$[n,n+1/n^2]$ where $(\star) $ is valid.

Comment: Thanks! could you please explain what led you to this step: Let $n_0$ be such that :

$(⋆) : |f(x)−f(y)|≤ 2(2/n_0+1/{n^2}_0)<ϵ.$

Comment: MathMan.Oops, you got me, I tried to retrace steps.I do not think it is wrong since$ |f(x)-f(y)| \le 2(1/n_0+1/n_0^4) \le 2(2/n_0+1/n_0^2) < \epsilon.$But why this choice?Let me know your thoughts.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. $x^2$ is increasing on this set, so it suffices just compare the endpoints of each interval, from which we see the decaying behavior 
$$(n+n^{-2})^2 - n^2 = 2n^{-1}+ n^{-4}$$
So if you pick $n\gg 1$ so that $2n^{-1}+ n^{-4}<\epsilon$, the function is constant up to $\epsilon$ errors on all intervals $[m,m+m^{-2}]$ for $m>n$. For the remaining intervals
$$ V=\bigcup_{i=1}^n [m,m+m^{-2}]$$
this is a compact set and $x^2$ is continuous, so it is automatically uniformly continuous.

To turn this into a proof: pick $\delta_1 $ so that for $x,y\in V$, $|x-y| \leq \delta_1 ⟹ |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Without loss $\delta_1 < 1/100$. Then for $x,y\not\in V$, if $|x-y|<\delta_1$ this means $x,y$ belong to the same interval $[m,m+m^{-2}]$, and by choice of $n$ above, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. for these points as well, which was to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

For each $\epsilon>0$ take $n_0$ as least positive integer where $(n_0+\frac{1}{n_0^2})^2-n_0^2=\frac{2}{n_0}+\frac{1}{n_0^4}<\epsilon$. Also take $\delta=\frac{1}{n_0^2}$. Obviously $\delta$ is a function of $\epsilon$ and for $x_1,x_2\in [n,n+\frac{1}{n^2}]$ where $n\ge n_0$ we have $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$ and for $x_1,x_2\in [n,n+\frac{1}{n^2}]$ where $n<n_0$ we have:
$$|x_2-x_1|<\delta=\frac{1}{n_0^2}\to |x_2^2-x_1^2|<|x_2+x_1|\frac{1}{n_0^2}\le \frac{2}{n_0^2}(n_0-1+\frac{1}{(n_0-1)^2})\le\frac{2n_0}{n_0^2}=\epsilon$$which is what we wanted to prove..